# How to auto-hide bookmarks bar in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks, gui, address-bar

I am looking for a way to auto-hide the bookmarks bar in Chrome, so that it only shows when I hover over the area.

I'd also like a method to auto-hide the address bar in Chrome that works in a similar fashion.

A Google search gave me [a method](http://www.howtogeek.com/93995/how-to-auto-hide-the-address-bar-in-google-chrome-and-chromium/) for the latter, but it doesn't seem to work any more (no "Compact Navigation") option in about:flags as far as I can see).

All suggestions welcome, including extensions.

Comment: In the meantime, you can press **Ctrl+Shift+B** to toggle on and off the Chrome bookmark toolbar. Additionally, you can press **F11** to toggle the Chrome full screen on and off. You might also look at this and see if you think this software would satisfy your need when in Full Screen mode putting the Chrome options near the bottom of the browser window: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabtiles/aaeapgfkbbbdpbfjmpcblemfajmkiddh?hl=en-US

Answer (score 11):

Try <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>, which hides bookmark bar when any website is opened and only shows in a new tab or home page.

Comment: For me it is showing all the time when I open it this way.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Windows computer, you can make the browser full-screen with F11. This auto-hides the address bar and bookmark bar and when you move your mouse to the top of the screen, it will show up again. However, both the address bar and bookmark bar will show up; as far as I know there is no way to make them show separately.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to permanently hide the bookmarks bar in Chrome. sadly this type of behaviour has led to a prevalence of junk "help" websites offering pretty much the same useless advice.

Ultimately until the feature is changed, another browser may be the answer.
I gets rather tedious using keystrokes for every tab. I suppose the developers at Google have a lot of screen real estate and don't think about people on 800x480 when adding these features, or assume they fullscreen by default.

Personally I have a page of bookmarks for my home page so I can remove the bookmarks from chrome. This does not suit everybody.